# Electronic/electrical actuator that HOLDS its position if power is lost?

Tags: actuator, electromagnetic

Is there any sort of electronic/electrical actuator that HOLDS its position if power is lost?

I am working on a project for a clutch actuator in an AWD system. One of the required tasks is to provide 3000N of force to a pressure plate which compresses a clutch pack.  This has to be accomplished by using the standard 12V or whatever you can get from an automobile.

The problem is, a design spec states that the clutch system needs to maintain its state if the vehicle has lost power.  This rules out the usage of an electromagnetic actuator, right?

The only thing I can think of doing is using some sort of mechanical lock after actuating with the electromagnetic actuator.

Would it make more sense to use a hydraulic actuator instead?

This actuation process needs to take no more than 200ms, so I'm not sure if something like a worm gear would be suitable (they tend to be slow, correct?)

Thanks in advance!

PS. If anyone has any recommendations of books about actuators in general, please mention them here!

Comment: it can be done. Wormgear with a rotational brake attached to the rotor

Comment: You need an electromagnetic brake for the motor shaft that is *released* by the application of power. They're actually quite common, since this sort of fail-safe operation is frequently required in industrial settings.

Comment: "Would it make more sense to use a hydraulic actuator instead?" Nope. In case of a leak, you will burn out the clutches.

Comment: Where is a good place to search for motors with built-in braking capability? I'm assuming these would be an off-the-shelf item that I could purchase. Appreciate the responses!

Answer (score 1):

Use a worm-drive / screw-drive linear actuator.  These are available in a ridiculously-large range of sizes, strengths, speeds, voltages.

The great thing about them is that the worm / screw drive inherently holds its' position when not moving.

Comment: ... if the drive ratio is high enough. It isn't a universally-true statement, however.

Comment: something about the angle of the worm grooves...

Comment: @Dave Tweed: you are correct.  I was generalizing and I shouldn't do that here.  That said: all of the linear actuators that I have worked with *are* self-locking.

Answer (score 0):

How about some sort of over-centre lever mechanism that's stable in two states, and snaps between them with an actuator?

You won't easily find a long stroke 3000 N electromagnetic solenoid, so you'll need a geared motor, so it may as well be a worm drive. Also, a long thread is a good way to generate a lot of force in a light mechanism... that's how I would drive a clutch.